# Use custom keyboard shortcut in lock screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, lock-screen, xinput

I have a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, if it matters) that runs the command:

```
xinput disable "some device name"
```

I want to be able to activate this shortcut/command even when my computer is locked. Ideally, it should even work if I've just booted and haven't typed in my password yet. Is there a way to do this?

Background: I have a faulty touchscreen, it sometimes goes haywire and registers a bunch of ghost input. I use this key combination to disable it quickly when it does. Without the keyboard shortcut, it's impossible to use the computer while this is happening - the false input overrides any attempted use of the mouse, and it constantly activates random things on the screen making even keyboard navigation impossible.

I do use the touchscreen sometimes so I don't want to disable it forever.

Comment: A bit off-topic... Asus is freaking terrible. Bought a premium product, and it broke to this unusable state immediately after warranty ran out. They offered no support and basically shrugged me off with no shame. So uhh, if anyone knows how I might be able to repair a faulty touch-screen, let me know. And don't buy Asus junk.

Comment: Maybe a better option is to blacklist the touchscreen driver.

Comment: As I said - I do use the touchscreen sometimes. This issue doesn't always happen, and when it's working correctly I prefer to use it.