# "Keyboard battery low" for laptop's built-in device

Tags: laptop, asus, wireless-keyboards

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my laptop, an asus UX461UN (zenbook flip 14). Every now and then I get a notification "Keyboard battery low", even though I have absolutely nothing connected. For some reason the laptop's built-in keyboard is reporting 1% battery, even when my laptop is fully charged and/or charging.

<del>How do I fix this? What is causing Ubuntu to think the keyboard has a battery?</del>

**How do I disable battery warnings for this device?**

[image: Power Statistics - Device Information]

Edit: I've just realized that this device isn't even the keyboard. It's the touchscreen, and in fact it is disabled most of the time (using `xinput disable <id>`) for [unrelated reasons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186230/use-custom-keyboard-shortcut-in-lock-screen).

Comment: I think it is almost definitely faulty or otherwise non-compliant hardware, asus does some pretty weird shit. So I would just like to know how to disable the notification for this device. I will try to perform that test at some point but I don't have much time to mess with this in the next few days, sorry

Comment: You're right, I've edited the question now. FWIW the hardware is *definitely* faulty in at least one way but this specific behavior might or might not be related to the fault.

Comment: Same issue on ASUS Vivobook 15 running 19.10.

Comment: I found this because I'm having the same problem. Settings > Notifications worked for me.

Comment: Did you disable all notifications?  Could you give more details.